# SSRS Data Source Network-related error from Report Server but VS works

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that is connecting to a new server.

When I run the report in Visual Studio, it runs fine but when I deploy the report, the new data source is getting an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The Type is MS SQL Server and the Connection String is basic (Data Source=;Initial Catalog=). When I hit Test, it takes about a minute to come up with the error. I also get the error whether using stored credentials or Windows Integrated.

I have recreated the data source by hand without any difference.

I have went through the Microsoft troubleshooting without success. I have numerous other similar data sources but have never had this issue.

[MS Docs: Troubleshoot connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Don't know what else to try. Any suggestions to fix this?

```
SSRS 2015 - SQL Server 13.0.5820.21
```

Comment: A few quick tings that popped into  my head. 1. I assume that remote connections ARE allowed on the remote server? 2. Can you connect using the remote server's IP address? 3. Can you ping the remote server directly from the server running SSRS either via it's name or IP address?

Comment: @AlanSchofield - Y, Y, Y. Also when I change the Data Source to Credentials Not Required, it immediately comes back as "The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset." which is correct.